# How to write react JS variable in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am rendering the following code in my react JS:

```
    <a href="http://localhost/PHP-React-Demo/update_record.html?id="{stud.id}>//this code I want to create a link dynamically with this.
```

I want to link this with particular ID now I an getting error as:

`Parse Error:object` as returned from `jstransform`

Comment: Error: Error: Parse Error: Line 38: Unexpected identifier
    at http://localhost/PHP-React-Demo/ajax_call.html

... Demo/update_record.html?id="{d.id}>Edit</a></td>
                                ^
 

* @return {object} object as returned from jstransform

Comment: Are you using babel to transpile the react code? or plain javascript?

if babel, you can try string interpolation `http://localhost/PHP-React-Demo/update_record.html?id=${stud.id}`

Comment: if pure js, `var link = "http://localhost/PHP-React-Demo/update_record.html?id=";`

`link += stud.id;`
`<a href={link} ... />`

Comment: it links to the same localhost/PHP-React-Demo/update_record.html?id=${stud.id}

Comment: @Road I am using react JS and rendering the data table format

Comment: Please consider paying more attention with the question formatting, in this case the question is inside the code and is not clear at all. An edit would be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href={ "http://localhost/PHP-React-Demo/update_record.html?id=" + stud.id}>
```

React does not work as a string replacement, everything gets compiled down to functions which then execute. By adding your string into the braces, you'll end up with something that will `return "string" + variable`, which is what will eventually end up in your HTML.

The compiled code will end up something like:

```
element.setAttribute( 'href', "<a href="http://localhost/PHP-React-Demo/update_record.html?id=" + stud.id )
```

React handles things like getting the element and making sure `stud.id` is in scope (amongst many other things)